# Mobius strip to the Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, klein-bottle, mobius-band

From the Youtube, I noticed that the Klein bottle can be sliced into two Mobius strips. Or this experiment is also explained in this following link: http://www.kleinbottle.com/sliced_klein_bottles.htm

So, given that I got the surface area of the Mobius strip, **can I calculate the surface area of the Klein bottle?** But the problem here, I think is, that the Klein bottle used in this experiment actually is the 3 dimensional one with the self-intersecting part, while the theoretical and ideal Klein bottle only lives in 4 dimensional space without self-intersection.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" Klein bottle? By scaling one can get a topological Klein bottle of any desired surface area.

Comment: @arctictern I mean the bottle-shaped Klein bottle which exists in the 3 dimensional space. What do you mean by 'scaling one'?

Comment: There are super-mega-infinitely many different-looking immersions of a topological Klein bottle in three-dimensional space. You can take any one you want and squish and squash and twist and whatever to it and get many different versions of a Klein bottle. For any possible value $A$, there is an immersion of a Klein bottle in 3D which has surface area $A$ (suitably interpreted). Even if we restrict to a specific figure (i.e. [similarity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry))), there is always a version with any area $A$.

Comment: To see this, take any immersion you want, then scale it. Scaling means shrinking or enlargening by a certain factor. For instance, to double a figure's size, where the figure is interpreted as a function into $\Bbb R^n$, one multiplies by $2$. For a toy example, take circles. Suppose someone asked, "what is the length of the circle"? It wouldn't make sense, because there are many different circles, and given a specific one you can always shrink or grow it to get any possible length. You can also stretch or modify it - *any* closed curve will be the immersion of a topological circle.

Comment: If you want to imagine just a single immersion (or, better, a Riemannian manifold which is topologically a Klein bottle, so we're talking about the surface intrinsically) - so, say, that specific toy model as displayed in the link - well, the total surface area will not be changed by cutting it up into two Mobius strips, so that's trivial.

Comment: @arctictern Oh, that analogy of length of the circle helped me a lot. Now I understand why you were asking what is 'the' specific Klein bottle that I mean. My understanding and description about the Klein bottle was insufficient :(

Comment: @arctictern What do you think if I get a specific parameterised equation for the Klein bottle with a specific value for the parameters and find the matching size of the Mobius strips? Of course these two Mobius strips will have specific values for their parameters. Is this sound better?

Comment: Sure. Then see my last previous comment. Cutting out a closed one-dimensional curve from a two-dimensional Riemannian manifold does not change the total surface area. For instance if you cut a ball in half, the surface area of the two halves added (assuming you have not flattened them and they retain the same shape) yields the original area of the sphere.

Comment: @arctictern Actually, what I wanted to do for my project is calculating the surface area of the specific Mobius strip from the matching size of the 'torus' and finally calculate the (again) matching size of the Klein bottle. But based on your suggestion, I should change the last part of my question to calculating specific parameter value of the Klein bottle from the given surface area.

Comment: No idea what you're saying.

Comment: @arctictern I thought the explanation will get longer, so I wrote it as another question. Would you check my new question please? This is the link for it; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877724/2-mobius-strip-torus-and-the-klein-bottle